# Is there more biomass on earth today than there was in the past?

Tags: evolution, palaeontology

Is there more, (or less) matter on earth sequestered as a part of biological systems than there was at any(arbitrary) time in the past?

Edit:

I realise I don't have a specific question, and was looking for a lesson of sorts on *what is the footprint of life* and *will the new not come if the old doesn't die and dissolve*(biologically atleast).

If you could suggest me good sources to study this, that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. As written the answer to your question is almost certainly yes and no depending on those arbitrary times. Rewriting your question so that it is clearer, more focused, and indicates why you want this information is likely to get a better response. We also encourage you to do some research and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: All the coal, limestone, and other bio-deposited stuff on Earth attests to the fact that past life has left behind a giant, cumulative mass of modified matter.  Even components of our atmosphere would be part of that mass.  Some of all that gets recycled by living organisms, and some gets modified by geological processes so that it may be hard to distinguish from "non-biomodified" matter.

Comment: @S.McGrew I am not talking about bio-modified matter as much as matter which forms the bodies etc. of living organisms.

Comment: Then that would include limestone, coal, & peat.  Marble is metamorphosed limestone.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess there was more in the past during warmer periods.  For example, imagine if Antarctica was covered in lush jungle rather than ice, then all else equal, there'd have been more biomass back then.  But  I don't think all else would have been equal, as it seems warmer temperatures promote more developed ecosystems in general, so all the rest of the continents would likely have had more biomass.  And of course, with tectonic drift, there were likely times when the large desert areas like the Sahara would have been in different areas with more rainfall and more biomass.  Plus, certainly during past periods of dramatic volcanic activity, all of the nutrients landing in the ocean would have led to much more phytoplankton which would have supported more ocean biomass as well.  Currently, many parts of the ocean simply can't support that much life since there aren't any nutrients in the water.